# Normalizer of $\langle(123), (456)\rangle\ \subset S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find the normalizer of $\langle(123), (456)\rangle\ \subset S_6$. Then only way I can think of is to check element by element whether $g \in S_6$ takes the $(123), (456)$  back to the subgroup generated by them . But that seems to be a mission impossible since $S_6$ is to "large".

Comment: Is the second permutation $(345)$ or $(456)$?

Comment: should be $( 456 )$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the normalizer of $\langle (123),(456)\rangle$ in $S_6$ has to preserve the partition $123\mid456$, so it is a subgroup of $S_3\operatorname{wr}C_2$.  Clearly it is normalized by $S_3\times S_3$, so we need to check whether $(14)(25)(36)$ normalizes this subgroup, and it clearly does.  So the normalizer is $S_3\operatorname{wr}C_2$.

Comment: \Sorry I am confused, but what do you mean by wr?

Comment: [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product).